# Scale marker size relative to the zoom level in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to decrease the size of the markers when the zoom level of the map is increased. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `interpolate` expression with the `zoom` expression, along these lines:

```
"icon-size": ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['zoom'], 10, 1, 15, 0.5]
```

Documentation here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#ramps-scales-curves

Comment: how do you implement that in a mapboxgl.Marker()?

Comment: That would be completely different. Feel free to ask that question.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870324/how-to-implement-mapbox-expression-inside-marker

Comment: Does GMaps support a similar feature as Mapbox?